# SSRS 2008 R2 Get Human Readable Schedule Information from ReportServer DB

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am looking to extract "human readable" schedule information from the ReportServer.dbo.Schedule table using t-sql.

An example of "human readable" follows.

`At 6:02 AM every Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat of every week, starting 2/28/2011`

There are a bunch of numeric fields in the table which are used to store the schedule, but I would like to convert those to words, as in my example.

Has anyone ever done this with reporting services?

Comment: Why in the he double hockey stick did someone vote to close this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQL is not great for string manipulation or bitwise operations, and parsing this table requires a moderate bit of both. I'm sure SSRS doesn't do this in SQL: I probably could have written this in half the time and half the lines in C#.

```
USE ReportServer;
WITH    EnhancedSched
          AS (
               SELECT
                dbo.Schedule.ScheduleID ,
                dbo.Schedule.Name ,
                dbo.Schedule.StartDate ,
                dbo.Schedule.Flags ,
                dbo.Schedule.NextRunTime ,
                dbo.Schedule.LastRunTime ,
                dbo.Schedule.EndDate ,
                dbo.Schedule.RecurrenceType ,
                dbo.Schedule.MinutesInterval ,
                dbo.Schedule.DaysInterval ,
                dbo.Schedule.WeeksInterval ,
                dbo.Schedule.DaysOfWeek ,
                dbo.Schedule.DaysOfMonth ,
                dbo.Schedule.Month ,
                dbo.Schedule.MonthlyWeek ,
                dbo.Schedule.State ,
                dbo.Schedule.LastRunStatus ,
                dbo.Schedule.ScheduledRunTimeout ,
                dbo.Schedule.CreatedById ,
                dbo.Schedule.EventType ,
                dbo.Schedule.EventData ,
                dbo.Schedule.Type ,
                dbo.Schedule.ConsistancyCheck ,
                dbo.Schedule.Path ,
                CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 1 <> 0 THEN 'Sun, '
                     ELSE ''
                END + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 2 <> 0 THEN 'Mon, '
                           ELSE ''
                      END + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 4 <> 0 THEN 'Tue, '
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 8 <> 0 THEN 'Wed, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 16 <> 0 THEN 'Thu, '
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 32 <> 0 THEN 'Fri, '
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 64 <> 0 THEN 'Sat, '
                                   ELSE ''
                              END AS DaysOfWeekString ,
                CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1 <> 0 THEN '1,'
                     ELSE ''
                END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2 <> 0 THEN '2,'
                           ELSE ''
                      END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4 <> 0 THEN '3,'
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8 <> 0 THEN '4,'
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16 <> 0 THEN '5,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 32 <> 0 THEN '6,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 64 <> 0 THEN '7,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 128 <> 0 THEN '8,'
                                         ELSE ''
                                    END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 256 <> 0 THEN '9,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 512 <> 0 THEN '10,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1024 <> 0 THEN '11,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2048 <> 0 THEN '12,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4096 <> 0 THEN '13,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8192 <> 0 THEN '14,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16384 <> 0 THEN '15,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 32768 <> 0 THEN '16,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 65536 <> 0 THEN '17,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 131072 <> 0 THEN '18,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 262144 <> 0 THEN '19,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 524288 <> 0 THEN '20,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1048576 <> 0 THEN '21,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2097152 <> 0 THEN '22,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4194304 <> 0 THEN '23,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8388608 <> 0 THEN '24,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16777216 <> 0 THEN '25,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 33554432 <> 0 THEN '26,'
                                   ELSE ''
                              END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 67108864 <> 0 THEN '27,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 134217728 <> 0 THEN '28,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 268435456 <> 0 THEN '29,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 536870912 <> 0 THEN '30,'
                             ELSE ''
                        END
                + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1073741824 <> 0 THEN '31,'
                       ELSE ''
                  END AS DaysOfMonthString ,
                CASE WHEN Month = 4095 THEN 'every month, '
                     ELSE CASE WHEN Month & 1 <> 0 THEN 'Jan, '
                               ELSE ''
                          END + CASE WHEN Month & 2 <> 0 THEN 'Feb, '
                                     ELSE ''
                                END + CASE WHEN Month & 4 <> 0 THEN 'Mar, '
                                           ELSE ''
                                      END
                          + CASE WHEN Month & 8 <> 0 THEN 'Apr, '
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN Month & 16 <> 0 THEN 'May, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END + CASE WHEN Month & 32 <> 0 THEN 'Jun, '
                                             ELSE ''
                                        END
                          + CASE WHEN Month & 64 <> 0 THEN 'Jul, '
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN Month & 128 <> 0 THEN 'Aug, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END
                          + CASE WHEN Month & 256 <> 0 THEN 'Sep, '
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN Month & 512 <> 0 THEN 'Oct, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END
                          + CASE WHEN Month & 1024 <> 0 THEN 'Nov, '
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + CASE WHEN Month & 2048 <> 0 THEN 'Dec, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                  END
                END AS MonthString ,
                CASE MonthlyWeek
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'first'
                  WHEN 2 THEN 'second'
                  WHEN 3 THEN 'third'
                  WHEN 4 THEN 'fourth'
                  WHEN 5 THEN 'last'
                END AS MonthlyWeekString ,
                ' starting ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, StartDate, 101)
                + CASE WHEN EndDate IS NOT NULL
                       THEN ' and ending ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, EndDate, 101)
                       ELSE ''
                  END AS StartEndString ,
                CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) % 12)
                  WHEN 0 THEN '12'
                  ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) % 12)
                END + ':'
                + CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDate) < 10
                       THEN '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE,
                                                              StartDate))
                       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDate))
                  END + CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) >= 12 THEN ' PM'
                             ELSE ' AM'
                        END AS StartTime
               FROM
                Schedule
             ),
        SuperEnhancedSchedule
          AS (
               SELECT
                EnhancedSched.ScheduleID ,
                EnhancedSched.Name ,
                EnhancedSched.StartDate ,
                EnhancedSched.Flags ,
                EnhancedSched.NextRunTime ,
                EnhancedSched.LastRunTime ,
                EnhancedSched.EndDate ,
                EnhancedSched.RecurrenceType ,
                EnhancedSched.MinutesInterval ,
                EnhancedSched.DaysInterval ,
                EnhancedSched.WeeksInterval ,
                EnhancedSched.DaysOfWeek ,
                EnhancedSched.DaysOfMonth ,
                EnhancedSched.Month ,
                EnhancedSched.MonthlyWeek ,
                EnhancedSched.State ,
                EnhancedSched.LastRunStatus ,
                EnhancedSched.ScheduledRunTimeout ,
                EnhancedSched.CreatedById ,
                EnhancedSched.EventType ,
                EnhancedSched.EventData ,
                EnhancedSched.Type ,
                EnhancedSched.ConsistancyCheck ,
                EnhancedSched.Path , -- spec what you need.
                CASE WHEN RecurrenceType = 1
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on '
                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 101)
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 2
                     THEN 'Every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( MinutesInterval / 60 ))
                          + ' hour(s) and '
                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( MinutesInterval % 60 ))
                          + ' minute(s), ' + 'starting '
                          + CONVERT (VARCHAR, StartDate, 101) + ' at '
                          + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 8), 0, 6)
                          + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 109),
                                            25, 2)
                          + CASE WHEN EndDate IS NOT NULL
                                 THEN ' and ending '
                                      + CONVERT (VARCHAR, EndDate, 101)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 3
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' every '
                          + CASE DaysInterval
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'day, '
                              ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DaysInterval) + ' days, '
                            END + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 4
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' every '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfWeekString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfWeekString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfWeekString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of every '
                          + CASE WHEN WeeksInterval = 1 THEN ' week,'
                                 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, WeeksInterval)
                                      + ' weeks,'
                            END + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 5
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on day(s) '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfMonthString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfMonthString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfMonthString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of ' + MonthString + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 6
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on the ' + MonthlyWeekString
                          + ' '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfWeekString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfWeekString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfWeekString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of ' + MonthString + StartEndString
                     ELSE 'At ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 8), 0,
                                            6) + ' '
                          + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 109), 25, 2)
                          + StartEndString
                END ScheduleTextDefinition
               FROM
                EnhancedSched
             )
    SELECT
        *
    -- This has the same columns as the native [dbo].Schedule table plus a field called "SheduleTextDefinition"
    -- You can use "SuperEnhancedSchedule" in place of the usual SSRS.Schedule table, joining to subscriptions and such.
    FROM
        SuperEnhancedSchedule
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to take into account when the schedule is once a month, or twice a month, etc. correct? do you see this more as a starting point?

Comment: Ill upvote it...because I've worked a ton on the internals of the reportserver database and it is not fun at times.  Be careful when dealing with M$ databases, you could easily void your warranty.  See my profile or google Power of the reportserver to read some of my articles, they may help.

Answer (score 2):

This post may be very old, but it helped me out today!
I found 2 items that I would like to add in the excellent post above by Jamie F for his CTE.

There was a missing entry for day 31 that needs to be added in as part of the EnhancedSched CTE, the below needs to be added to the end of the 'DaysOfMonthString'

```
+ CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1073741824 <> 0 THEN '31,' ELSE '' END
```

Also, the 'StartTime' column definition with the modulo 12 makes any time beginning with 12 a zero, so the plain English result shows a start time of 0:30 PM for something that is supposed to say 12:30 pm.
Replace the

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hour, StartDate) % 12)
```

with

```
CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hour, StartDate) % 12) WHEN 0 THEN '12' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hour, StartDate) % 12) END
```

to get the plain English start time to read properly.

Mega thanks to Jamie F's post above, saved my bacon. +1 internets for you good sir.

Sorry for the extra 'answer' post, no rep to comment to up-vote Jamie F's excellent post above.

Comment: Thanks! Fixes incorporated into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a stored procedure in the MSDB  database called ***sp_get_schedule_description*** that can generate the schedule descriptions. I have the code below writting the schedule ID and the human-readable description to a ***ScheduleInfo*** user table. It works very well but the user running the code will need read-access to the msdb database and execute permissions to the SP for it to work.

```
DECLARE @schedule_description   NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @freq_type              INT
DECLARE @freq_interval          INT
DECLARE @freq_subday_type       INT
DECLARE @freq_subday_interval   INT
DECLARE @freq_relative_interval INT
DECLARE @freq_recurrence_factor INT
DECLARE @active_start_date      INT
DECLARE @active_end_date        INT
DECLARE @active_start_time      INT
DECLARE @active_end_time        INT
DECLARE @schedule_id_as_char    VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @scheduleID           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE @resultCursor           CURSOR

-- Create cursor using records from job schedules in MSDB database
--
SET @resultCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
d.freq_type
,d.freq_interval
,d.freq_subday_type
,d.freq_subday_interval
,d.freq_relative_interval
,d.freq_recurrence_factor
,d.active_start_date
,d.active_end_date
,d.active_start_time
,d.active_end_time
,a.ScheduleID
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Schedule a
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs b on CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),a.ScheduleID) = b.name 
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules c on b.job_id = c.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules d on c.schedule_id = d.schedule_id

OPEN @resultCursor

-- Fetch first record from cursor
--
FETCH NEXT
FROM @resultCursor INTO
@freq_type 
,@freq_interval 
,@freq_subday_type
,@freq_subday_interval
,@freq_relative_interval
,@freq_recurrence_factor
,@active_start_date
,@active_end_date
,@active_start_time
,@active_end_time
,@scheduleID

-- Loop through cursor and get the rest of the records
--
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Call stored prc in MSDB database to get schedule description
    --
    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_get_schedule_description
    @freq_type,
    @freq_interval,
    @freq_subday_type,
    @freq_subday_interval,
    @freq_relative_interval,
    @freq_recurrence_factor,
    @active_start_date,
    @active_end_date,
    @active_start_time,
    @active_end_time,
    @schedule_description OUTPUT

    -- Insert record to ScheduleInfo table
    --
    INSERT INTO ScheduleInfo VALUES (@scheduleID, @schedule_description)

    -- Get the next record from the cursor
    -- 
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @resultCursor INTO
    @freq_type 
    ,@freq_interval 
    ,@freq_subday_type
    ,@freq_subday_interval
    ,@freq_relative_interval
    ,@freq_recurrence_factor
    ,@active_start_date
    ,@active_end_date
    ,@active_start_time
    ,@active_end_time
    ,@scheduleID


END

--Close cursor
--
CLOSE @resultCursor
DEALLOCATE @resultCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this as it came up for a report I am writing.

```
create function [dbo].[calendarlist](@Value_in as int,@Type as int) returns varchar(200)
as
begin

/*
This code is to work out either the day of the week or the name of a month when given a value
Wrriten by S Manson.
31/01/2012
*/

declare @strings as varchar(200)
declare @Count int

if @Type = 2    --Months
    Begin
        set @Count =12
    end
else if @Type = 1   --Days of Week
    Begin
        Set @Count = 7
    End
else    --Days of Month
    Begin
        Set @Count = 31
    End

set @strings = ''

while @Count<>0
begin
    if @Value_in>=(select power(2,@count-1))
        begin
            set @Value_in = @Value_in - (select power(2,@count-1))
            If @Type=2
                Begin
                    set @strings = (SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(month, @count-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))) + ',' + @strings
                end
            else if @Type = 1
                begin
                    set @strings = (SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, @count-1, CAST('2012-01-01' AS datetime)))) + ',' + @strings
                end
            else
                begin
                    set @strings = convert(varchar(2),@Count) + ', ' + @strings
                end

        end
    set @count = @count-1
end
if right(@strings,1)=','
    set @strings = left(@strings,len(@strings)-1)

return @strings

end
```